# Beyond Compare 4 ignore a line in all files if certain text occure in a line

Tags: regex, beyondcompare4

In Beyond Compare 4 how can one ignore a line as unimportant line in all files if certain text occure in this line ?

E.g.

File1:

```
I am master 
I live with family
Fear is common
I mean simple 1179
```

File2:

```
I am MASTER 1179
I live alone
Fear is COMMON 1179
The 1179 be specific is a number
```

When I find differences it should only show Line 2 & Line 4:

```
> I live with family < I live alone
> I mean simple 1179 < The 1179 be specific is a number
```

Note : i tried the grammar `.*1179.*` but i still see all lines in differences

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the grammar.

Click on the `Rules` button then select the `Importance` tab and add

```
^.*(common|master).*$
```

as a `Regular expression`.

The line 1 and 3 will be marked as *unimportant* as showed here:

[image]

Comment: To affect all files in a parent Folder Compare session or change Text Compare session defaults, change "Use for this view only" at the bottom of the dialog to "Use for all files within parent session" or "Also update session defaults" before you click OK. To make the unimportant text show as a match (black text) instead of unimportant (blue) make sure "View > Ignore Unimportant Differences" is turned on.